# how to remove markers from p:chart in primefaces

Tags: primefaces, jqplot

I'm using primefaces 5.2. I want to remove markers of lines in p:chart. showMarker option is not working. I googled also, but i couldn't find any answer. Anyone have any idea about this?

```
<p:chart type="line" model="#{graphController.chartModel}" style="height:450px;width:790px"/>
```

Comment: Search the jqplot forum...show code etc...

Comment: This is my code. And I tried javascript also, but showMarker was not working.

<p:chart type="line" model="#{graphController.chartModel}" style="height:450px;width:790px"/>

Comment: Thank you for replying. :) I found the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
function format() {
    this.cfg.seriesDefaults = {
        showMarker: false
    }
}
```

this is working for me. :) p:chart is not defined attribute as p:linechart. But there is a way to set it in the bean class.

```
private void createLineModels() {
    LineChartModel chartModel = new LineChartModel();
    chartModel.setExtender("format");
}
```

Comment: And where and howdo you use that?

Comment: I used in the javascript tags and javascript put in body content.

Comment: I'm new to this :(. Sorry for delay to edit the post.

Comment: This javascript by itself will still do nothing. How is it called? That is very relevant to the answer.

Comment: Worked for me. I am using primefaces 5.3. Thanks!